# How to use Interface from @types/socket.io

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

I Have followed [How-to-use socket.io with typescript article](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/typescript-socket-io-tutorial/).

In the article, they are installing `@types/socket.io`.
However, when they are declaring a function that needs to get a socket, they are using the type: `any`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket: any){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

in the repository of  `@types/socket.io` , [i have found an Interface for `Socket`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/44ea6863ba0672f8031985e5faf9fda76e786e7c/types/socket.io/index.d.ts#L503)

When i'm trying to define the function in that way:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket: Socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

I get an error: `Cannot find name 'Socket'.`

How can I use the interface for Socket based [on the code of the article](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/typescript-socket-io-tutorial/)?

Comment: Have you installed the typing correctly? Do you see socket folder inside @types folder of node_modules?

Comment: Try this: SocketIO.Socket

Comment: @Drag13 Yay, it seems to solve the problem

Comment: Should I add an answer for this?

Comment: Up to you, if you want the upvote (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main idea is to open .d.ts file and check what does it export.

If you open that index.d.ts you will find next code

```
declare const SocketIO: SocketIOStatic;
export = SocketIO;
export as namespace SocketIO;
```

As you see, it exports SocketIO as a namespace. So we can access internal interfaces with this namespace, like here:

```
SocketIO.Socket
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you find thread while searching for the same thing with socket.io-client then use:

```
socket: SocketIOClient.Socket
```